# Best practice to import components in VueJS 2.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, components

I'm new with VueJs.

I have a question about which is the best practice about import components in A Vue Template Project. 
I have some components used in some views. Then I dowloaded a admin template, and the samples always import the components in the view. Included Vue declaration.  So I think that could be better import as global components. But I don't know if it have advantages or inconveniencies ( about the speed or the weight). 
Then my questions is about it. Which is the best practice? To the project works  fine.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your question is whether to import components globally, in the `new Vue({})`/`main.js` page, or locally as needed. Is that correct?

Importing them as needed reduces bundle size, but if you are reusing a component a lot, then maybe import that one globally.

The main consideration for me is whether I need to access info from `this.$options.components` (which will only return locally registered ones).

Answer (score 0):

as of right now the best way to import a Component into vue.js is

```
import Test from './Test.vue';
```

Comment: Thank you  for your fast reponse, but my doubt is about where is better to import. If import as a global component then only import it one time.  Or if better import every time I want to use it.

Comment: it dosent mather since at the end of the day it will be compiled into a single file wish will be served everytime a user acces your app so whether you import it globally or every time you wanna use it it dosent mather